# No background canvas for plain frame

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I created background canvas for my presentation. I **don't** want the image if the frame style is `plain`. How can I extend my style file that no background image appears if `\begin{frame}[plain]` is used.

What I already have

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}
    {\ifnum\thepage=1\relax%
        {%
        \includegraphics{Background_page1}
        }
        \else%
\includegraphics{Background}
     \fi%
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`beamer` has the boolean `beamer@plainframe` to decide whether the `plain` option is activated or not, so you can use it in your conditional installment of the `background canvas` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\ifbeamer@plainframe%
\else
  \ifnum\thepage=1\relax% 
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}% 
  \else 
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}% 
  \fi
\fi 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test regular frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{A test frame with the \texttt{plain} option}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Another test regular frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]